# Java - Return current class type

Tags: java, class, return

I have a class `Num`, a class `Num2` and a `Num2` instance as follows:

```
public class Num {
    private int num;
    public Num() {
        num = 0;
    }
    public Num add2() {
        this.num += 2;
        return this;
    }       
}
public class Num2 extends Num {}
Num2 n = new Num2();
```

When I use `n.add2()` I get a `Num` object. 
How can I inherit from Num to Num2 and "change" the return type respectively? 
Thank you!

Comment: Currently `Num2 n = new Num2();` is declared outside of any class. Something like that is not allowed in Java.

Comment: @Amongalen I wrote that for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can achieve this using the overriding and Downcasting concepts.**

**Sample solution:**

```
public class Num2 extends Num{

    @Override
    public Num2 add2() {

       return (Num2) super.add2();//Downcasting

    }       

}
```

Comment: Or `super.add2(); return this;` without any casting at all.